# How can I interpret this VB6 code?

Tags: vb6, postscript

I inherited a VB program that prints shipping labels.  We need to update the barcode that gets printed and I'm trying to understand what the existing program is doing.  There is a bunch of "WrittenData" (stored as "s") that seems to contain the Postscript code to produce the labels, but I haven't found anywhere that specifies the meaning of half this stuff.

```
Public Function PostScriptItem(address As Variant, Optional intPageNumberOut As Integer = 1, Optional intPageNumberIn As Integer = 2) As String

  ' 0 - MatchUpId
  ' 1 - Our Barcode
  ' 2 - Outgoing PostNet Code
  ' 3 - Outgoing Line 1
  ' 4 - Outgoing Line 2 (optionally EMPTY)
  ' 5 - Outgoing Line 3
  ' 6 - Outgoing Line 4
  ' 7 - Outgoing PlaNET Code
  ' 8 - Incoming PostNet Code
  ' 9 - Incoming Line 1
  '10 - Incoming Line 2 (optionally EMPTY)
  '11 - Incoming Line 3
  '12 - Incoming Line 4
  '13 - Incoming PlaNET Code
  '14 - Title Id

  'Escape Parenthesis and Backslashes
  Dim tPos As Integer
  For tPos = 0 To 14 Step 1
    address(tPos) = Replace(address(tPos), "\", "\\")
    address(tPos) = Replace(address(tPos), "(", "\(")
    address(tPos) = Replace(address(tPos), ")", "\)")
  Next tPos

  Dim s As String
  Dim pos As Integer
  Dim fsize As Integer

  Dim strBarcodeCaption As String

  strBarcodeCaption = address(1) & "    " & address(14) & "    " & address(0)

  pos = 50
  fsize = 12

  s = s & "%%Page: " & CStr(intPageNumberOut) & " " & CStr(intPageNumberOut) & vbCrLf & _
          "<< /Duplex true >> setpagedevice" & vbCrLf & _
          "<< /Tumble true >> setpagedevice" & vbCrLf & _
          "%%BeginPageSetup" & vbCrLf & _
          "180 rotate" & vbCrLf & _
          "/pagelevel save def" & vbCrLf & _
          "%%EndPageSetup" & vbCrLf & _
          "newpath" & vbCrLf & _
          "-338 -205 translate" & vbCrLf & _
          "/Courier-Bold findfont 6 scalefont setfont" & vbCrLf & _
          "newpath" & vbCrLf

  s = s & "32 104 moveto (" & strBarcodeCaption & ") show" & vbCrLf & _
          "newpath" & vbCrLf

  s = s & "12 -450 translate" & vbCrLf & _
          "62 104 moveto (" & strBarcodeCaption & ") show" & vbCrLf & _
          "newpath" & vbCrLf & _
          "30 80 moveto (^104" & address(1) & ") (height=0.3) code128 barcode" & vbCrLf & _
          "newpath" & vbCrLf

  s = s & "/Helvetica findfont 11 scalefont setfont" & vbCrLf & _
          "0 " & CStr(pos) & " moveto (" & address(3) & ") show" & vbCrLf & _
          "newpath" & vbCrLf

  pos = pos - fsize

  If address(4) <> Empty Then
    s = s & "0 " & CStr(pos) & " moveto (" & address(4) & ") show" & vbCrLf & _
            "newpath" & vbCrLf

    pos = pos - fsize
  End If

  s = s & "0 " & CStr(pos) & " moveto (" & address(5) & ") show" & vbCrLf & _
          "newpath" & vbCrLf

  pos = pos - fsize

  s = s & "0 " & CStr(pos) & " moveto (" & address(6) & ") show" & vbCrLf & _
          "newpath" & vbCrLf

  pos = pos - fsize - 5

  s = s & "1 " & CStr(pos) & " moveto (" & address(2) & ") () postnet barcode" & vbCrLf & _
          "%%PageTrailer" & vbCrLf & _
          "pagelevel restore" & vbCrLf & _
          "showpage" & vbCrLf

  s = s & "%%Page: " & CStr(intPageNumberIn) & " " & CStr(intPageNumberIn) & vbCrLf & _
          "<< /Duplex true >> setpagedevice" & vbCrLf & _
          "<< /Tumble true >> setpagedevice" & vbCrLf & _
          "%%BeginPageSetup" & vbCrLf & _
          "/pagelevel save def" & vbCrLf & _
          "210 711 translate" & vbCrLf & _
          "%%EndPageSetup" & vbCrLf & _
          "newpath" & vbCrLf & _
          "/Courier-Bold findfont 6 scalefont setfont" & vbCrLf & _
          "0 21 moveto (" & address(1) & "    " & address(0) & ") show" & vbCrLf & _
          "gsave" & vbCrLf & _
          "0.5 0.5 scale" & vbCrLf & _
          "0 12 moveto (^104" & address(1) & ") (height=0.3) code128 barcode" & vbCrLf & _
          "grestore" & vbCrLf & _
          "newpath" & vbCrLf & _
          "32 0 moveto (" & address(14) & ") show" & vbCrLf & _
          "newpath" & vbCrLf & _
          "/Helvetica findfont 11 scalefont setfont" & vbCrLf & _
          "-70 -180 translate" & vbCrLf

  pos = 56

  s = s & "0 " & CStr(pos) & " moveto (" & address(9) & ") show" & vbCrLf & _
          "newpath" & vbCrLf

  pos = pos - fsize

  If address(10) <> Empty Then
    s = s & "0 " & CStr(pos) & " moveto (" & address(10) & ") show" & vbCrLf & _
            "newpath" & vbCrLf

    pos = pos - fsize
  End If

  s = s & "0 " & CStr(pos) & " moveto (" & address(11) & ") show" & vbCrLf & _
          "newpath" & vbCrLf

  pos = pos - fsize

  s = s & "0 " & CStr(pos) & " moveto (" & address(12) & ") show" & vbCrLf & _
          "newpath" & vbCrLf

  pos = pos - fsize - 5

  s = s & "1 " & CStr(pos) & " moveto (" & address(8) & ") () postnet barcode" & vbCrLf & _
          "%%PageTrailer" & vbCrLf & _
          "pagelevel restore" & vbCrLf & _
          "showpage" & vbCrLf

  PostScriptItem = s

End Function
```

I need to change the contents of "address(2)" and "address(8)" and use a different font to print those.  I tried putting the new font in the projects fonts folder and referencing it the way "postnet" and "code128" are referenced but that left me with an entirely blank label.
The "code128" font seems to get defined in a separate file called "postscript_main.ps" and I have no idea how to incorporate the new font into that, I am really lost and hoping for a clue or a link to some documentation that might get me going in the right direction.

Comment: VB that generates Postscript? Now that's scary...

Comment: yeah and I'm not a VB guy at all, worked here 3 years and never had to touch this program before, written about 10 years ago...

Comment: you can try to add `/Helvetica findfont 11 scalefont setfont` before the "1 " & Cstr(pos) on your adress(2) line...

Comment: Might become handy: http://www.gnu.org/software/ghostscript/intro.html

Comment: what do you suppose the words "postnet" and "barcode" do on this line, are they functions or ? `s = s & "1 " & CStr(pos) & " moveto (" & address(2) & ") () postnet barcode" & vbCrLf & _`

Comment: the project has Images/postscript_main.ps file that has `% --BEGIN ENCODER postnet--` where it seems to define "postnet", wonder where I'd get the same for the new font?

Comment: What is the new font? postscript has a reversed order of arguments and functions, so it starts with the arguments and then calls a function. I believe that line might do something like: moveto(1,pos); barcode(postnet(address(2),null));

Comment: the new font is USPSIMBStandard.  On top of needing this font there's also a function for encoding the values, which I can hopefully get working once I get the font to actually work...

Comment: reevant stuff here .. https://ribbs.usps.gov/onecodesolution/download.cfm

Comment: Your on the right track, but without seeing "postscript_main.ps", it is impossible to guess what you need to change. The /Helvetica findfont 12 scalefont setfont is setting the font. in the postscript_main.ps, there has to be an equivalant call for the font. "postnet" is not a postscript command, so there has to be a /postnet { ... } def inside the .ps file to define the command. the "barcode" also isn;t a postscript command, so there has to be a /barcode { .... } def inside the file as well. Barcodes are binary codes, to the encoding translate your ascii to barcode data.